# How to create list button in lighting page

Tags: component

I created List button  by using java script on classic its not display list button  in lightning
its classic list button java script

```
var selectedvisibiltyIds = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.HR_Cases_Visibility__c)};
var visibiltysForUpdate = [];

if (selectedvisibiltyIds[0] == null) {
    alert('You must select at least one record');
} else {
    for (var i= 0; i < selectedvisibiltyIds.length; i++) {
       var visibilty = new sforce.SObject("HR_Cases_Visibility__c");
       visibilty.Id = selectedvisibiltyIds[i];
       visibilty.IsRemoved__c = true;
       visibiltysForUpdate.push(visibilty);
    }
}

if (confirm("Are you sure ?") == true) {
   var saveResult = sforce.connection.update(visibiltysForUpdate);

        for (var i= 0; i < saveResult.length; i++) {
        if(saveResult[i].success!='true'){ 
                alert(saveResult[i].errors.message);
                break;
            }
        }

   location.reload(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Visualforce Page with Lightning Enabled, Put just the Script in that, which you have used in the List Button. Create a new List Button which will open this Visualforce Page and you are done. Nothing else to do.

Example:

SampleListButtonVP:

```
<apex:page>
<script>
    (function(){
        {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.HR_Cases_Visibility__c)}; var visibiltysForUpdate = [];

        if (selectedvisibiltyIds[0] == null) { alert('You must select at least one record'); } else { for (var i= 0; i < selectedvisibiltyIds.length; i++) { var visibilty = new sforce.SObject("HR_Cases_Visibility__c"); visibilty.Id = selectedvisibiltyIds[i]; visibilty.IsRemoved__c = true; visibiltysForUpdate.push(visibilty); } }

        if (confirm("Are you sure ?") == true) { var saveResult = sforce.connection.update(visibiltysForUpdate);

            for (var i= 0; i < saveResult.length; i++) {
            if(saveResult[i].success!='true'){ 
                    alert(saveResult[i].errors.message);
                    break;
                }
            }
        location.reload(true); }
    })();
</script></apex:page>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you so much ! i tried this one but its not working

Comment: I assume you might have added required tags for the visualforce page to work it for List Buttons....

<apex;page standardController="Object For List Button here" recordSetVar="shs" extensions="If Required" title="New Support Handling Note">